# Cutting circular pie into seven equal parts

Tags: strategy

> your task is to cut this pie (shown below) into seven equal parts.
>   
>   [image]
>   
>   What equal means by is size and shape
>   
>   you have only one knife of length equal to cakes diameter and a scale to measure W and D but nothing else
>   Edit : Also there should be nothing of cake that that is wasted/eaten

Comment: Can't we just cut it into 8 and eat 1? :)

Comment: How equal is equal? Mathematical equal, or equal for all practical purposes?

Comment: edited it....but nice thought though :)

Comment: yes assuming no material is wasted in cutting then matematical and material equal holds true.

Comment: yes it will be each of width W/7 and diameter D

Comment: But how can you be sure? You just 'guess' something?

Comment: So cutting into sevenths by eye in the traditional way would be a equally valid answer?

Comment: @Bob I +1ed your comment because this is a vague and overly broad question, but I think the idea is that you have a ruler but not a protractor. So, say W is 7cm, then you can make horizontal incisions at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 cm heights using your ruler. But in order to cut slices of the right angle you would need something to help you measure 51.4°, and you don't have anything to do that with.

Comment: It's gonna be much much easier to cut 7 conventional slices just using the eye to judge the angle, than it is to make 7 perfectly level horizontal slices through the whole cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly solution:

> You cut through the Height? (the W in the picture). So you end up with 7 slices with the same diameter as the whole cake, but just 1/7th of its height.

Comment: +1 Answers are not silly....rather the way we think are :)

Comment: @user2408578 But what about the crust/icing. The top/bottom slice will get almost all of it!!

Comment: How do you plan to measure the height of each slice?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to cut a circle into 7 pieces using geometric methods: [Is it possible to divide a circle into 7 equial pizza slices...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440825/is-it-possible-to-divide-a-circle-into-7-equal-pizza-slices-using-geometric), unless you allow [Neusis construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction); see [Heptagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon%20Constructing%20a%20Heptagon) for details on constructing a Heptagon, which can be overlaid on the pie and used to guide the slicing.

The only good solution that avoids geometry is the height-based slicing, as suggested by Anon.

Answer (score 1):

> Place a quarter in the center of the pizza.
>  Arrange seven dimes around the quarter.
>  Insert seven toothpicks in the “V” between the dimes.
>  Use the tooth picks as a guide to slice the pizza to the perimeter.
>  All seven eaters may enjoy equal slices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

> You find the midway point of the radius of the cake. From there you would take a straight line across it from one side of the circle to the other. Then measure the distance from that midway point to the edge of the cake on this cross-section. Divide that in half. You now have the length you mark for the edge of each slice. Start at a point and measure out the length you got and make a mark. Do this until you have all seven slices.

Answer (score 0):

Eight easy steps:

1. Make incision marks around the perimeter as for it being cut into 8.
2. Then take one of the 8th pieces, and guessage it into 7 divisions.
3. Then cut the first slice according to a Sixth+theSeventhOfTheSixth.
4. Once cut down both sides to the centre, take it and lay it on top of the next slice you want to cut.
5. Make a deep cut.
6. Rinse and repeat until you've marked out the whole circle.
7. Cut into seven.
8. Send me money.

Comment: "guessage" seems a bit imprecise?